# Is there a more efficient way than String.split() to break up a String into words?

Tags: java, string

My current project requires a search to be run on lyrics of a song, which is a String field in the Song object.  To help make searches more efficient, I dump the lyric words into a set upon creation of the song object using `String.split("[^a-zA-Z]");` to make a String array, then add to a set.

Is there a specific way to add the words to a set without the intermediate step of creating an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you search some words in particular song? If so, you may not really need a set for this, you can run your search just from the point you got the lyrics. You can use plain regexp for this, this might be a way bit faster than splitting the String, putting it into a set and querying the set then:

```
public class RegexpExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String song = "Is this a real life? Is this just fantasy?";
    String toFind = "is";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(toFind, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(song);

    while (m.find()) {
        String found = m.group();
        int startIndex = m.start();
        int endIndex = m.end();

        System.out.println(found + " at start " + startIndex + ", end " + endIndex);
        //do something with this info...
    }
}
```

It will output this:

```
Is at start 0, end 2
is at start 5, end 7
Is at start 21, end 23
is at start 26, end 28
```

If you however search in different songs you can concatenate their lyrics using `StringBuilder`, then call `StringBuilder#toString` and do the whole operation with the result of `toString` method

Comment: The current project is running searches for particular words that do not match a list of common words.  Your solution seems best for phrase searching, which is the next project, and I will probably implement your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a specific way to add the words to a set without the
>   intermediate step of creating an array?

Sure, you could write a method that returns an `Iterator` object, which feeds out one word at a time.

But something like this really isn't worth optimizing away. Your array will easily be small enough to fit into memory, it's creation won't be that expensive, and the garbage collector will clean it up afterward.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("the days go on and on without you here");
HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    words.add(st.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: according to the javadocs: `StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.`  interesting solution, though

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about efficiency, but alternately, you could do it like this:

```
import java.io.StringReader;

// ...

public static Set<String> getLyricSet(String lyrics) throws IOException {
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(lyrics);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    int current;
    // Read characters one by one, returns -1 when we're done
    while ((current = sr.read()) != -1) {
        if (Character.isWhitespace(current)) {
            // End of word, add current word to set.
            set.add(sb.toString());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        } else {
            sb.append((char) current);
        }
    }
    // End of lyrics, add current word to set.
    set.add(sb.toString());
    sr.close();

    return set;
}
```